# How to make an axios POST request in React?

Tags: reactjs, axios

So, some context: Users submit a dog name via a text input, and this is controlled by the 'Dogue.jsx' component:

```js
import React from 'react';

class Dogue extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      id: props.id,
      nameInput: '',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      nameInput: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.inputFunction(this.state.nameInput);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.id);
    return (
      <div className="dogue-container">
        <img className="img" src={this.props.dogList} />
        <br />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
          <input
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            className="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter dog name"
          />
          <br />
          <button className="button">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <h2 className="text">Name: {this.props.name} </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dogue;
```

The submitted information is then passed to 'App.jsx', where it is used to update state:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './styles.css';
import DogList from './DogList';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      dog: [],
      dogName: [],
    };
    this.updateStateWithInput = this.updateStateWithInput.bind(this);
  }

  setData = async () => {
    const x = await fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images');
    const y = await x.json();
    const z = await y.message;

    let newArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      if (i <= 9) {
        newArr.push(z[i]);
      }
    }
    return newArr;
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
    });

    let dogPromise = await this.setData();
    let dogNamePromise = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/dogs');

    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      dog: dogPromise,
      dogName: dogNamePromise.data,
    });
  }

  updateStateWithInput(nameInput) {
    //Here is where state is updated.
    //change state, then use axios.post to submit data
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.loading ? (
      <h1 className="text"> Dogues Loading.....</h1>
    ) : (
      <div>
        <h1 className="text">Rate My Dogue</h1>
        <DogList
          dogs={this.state.dog}
          name={this.state.dogName}
          inputFunction={this.updateStateWithInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The updated state, I imagine, will be used in the axios post request to submit data to the database. So, I've got input data being sent from Dogue to App, I'm just not sure what to do now? The information currently in state looks as follows:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    dogName: 'bruce',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    dogName: 'borker',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    dogName: 'henry',
  },
];
```

I should also show my map function, in DogList.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Dogue from './Dogue';

const DogList = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="img-container">
      {props.dogs.map((doggie, index) => {
        return (
          <Dogue
            id={props.name[index] && props.name[index].id}
            key={index}
            dogList={doggie}
            name={props.name[index] && props.name[index].dogName}
            inputFunction={props.inputFunction}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DogList;
```

Comment: Could you share the data(and format, if possible) that will exactly be `POST`ed?

Comment: You can pass your ```UPDATE DOG``` or ```SUBMIT_DOG``` , ```POST``` action function, as a prop. or in ```DOG``` directly. But it is better to use ```Redux``` or ```React Context API```.

Comment: @KPranavRam the data to be posted is just a string.

Comment: Do you by chance know how the server will process it ,for specificity; or do you want a generic way of `POST`ing in axios?

Answer (score 0):

You can send a `POST` request with axios by calling:

```
axios.post(url, data, options);
```

It’s similar to the way you called the get method to make a `GET` request.

I’m leaving this axios cheat sheet here since it’s really useful until you get the hang of it:

https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index

Comment: Thanks for the answers, folks! I've just written the following code which posted stuff to the database, just not in the right way. It needs to take the input (a dog name in the form of a string) and then add it to the list of other names in the database. Here's what I wrote:
 ``` async updateStateWithInput (nameInput) {
  this.setState({
    id: Date.now(),
    dogName:nameInput
  })
  await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/dogs',({
    id:this.state.id,
    dogName:this.state.dogName
  }))}
   ```